# How secure is the server if someone has access to the magento admin panel

Tags: security

How secure would the server that magento runs in be if someone was to have access to the magento admin panel.

**Is there a way through extensions installed or similar techniques to install malware on the server?**

**Is it a good idea to trust a freelancer with the admin panel login info to make any installs or adjustments?**

Comment: You can always do things yourself if you don't trust said freelancer. I don't know what your contract is with them, but things should be pretty clear for your safety.

Comment: The thing is, I trust them but not enough to give them ssh access to the server but good enough to have access to the magento site. The thing I am worried the most is if they manage to install with any of the magento extensions and php plugins some malware

Comment: Better do a screen share and you can still see what the freelancer is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hire a freelancer then you have to trust them.
But if you have any doubt on them then you can create a admin user for limited access and give that access to them.

So you will feel secure.

Comment: ok so you can create temporary admin user for freelancers with limited access